# Linkage error after doing changes in programming code

Tags: bash, command-line, opensuse, make

I had a program running with a certain number generator and I switched to another one that is already in CUDA (CURAND), I tried changing my `makefile` accordingly but this is causing linkage errors I can't understand, here is my `main()`

I am getting the following errors:

```
nvcc -lm -lpthread main.o parser.o black_scholes.o -o hw1.x
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `black_scholes'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:24: hw1.x] Error 1
```

Here is my `makefile`:

```
include Makefile.include


HW1_INCS = black_scholes.h parser.h timer.h util.h
HW1_C_SRCS = main.c parser.c
HW1_CUDA_SRCS = black_scholes.cu
HW1_C_OBJS = $(HW1_C_SRCS:.c=.o)
HW1_CUDA_OBJS = $(HW1_CUDA_SRCS:.cu=.o)
HW1_EXE = hw1.x

all: hw1.x

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(ACCFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o: %.cu
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(ACCFLAGS) $< -o $@

hw1.x: $(HW1_C_OBJS) $(HW1_CUDA_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(HW1_C_OBJS) $(HW1_CUDA_OBJS) -o $@

black_scholes.o: black_scholes.cu black_scholes.h util.h
main.o: main.c black_scholes.h parser.h
parser.o: parser.c parser.h
util.o: util.c util.h

clean:
    rm -f $(HW1_C_OBJS) $(HW1_CUDA_OBJS) $(HW1_EXE)
```

Here is my `makefile.include`

```
CC = nvcc

COPTFLAGS = -O2

CPPFLAGS = 

CFLAGS = $(COPTFLAGS)

LINKER = nvcc

LDFLAGS = -lm -lpthread
```

and in case it is relevant, here is my `main()`

```
#include "black_scholes.h"
#include "parser.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  confidence_interval_t interval;
  double S, E, r, sigma, T;
  int M = 0;
  char* filename = NULL;
  int nthreads = 1;
  double t1, t2;
  
  if (argc < 3)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, 
           "Usage: ./hw1.x <filename> <nthreads>\n\n");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  filename = argv[1];
  nthreads = to_int (argv[2]);
  parse_parameters (&S, &E, &r, &sigma, &T, &M, filename);

  
  black_scholes (&interval, S, E, r, sigma, T, M, nthreads);

  printf ("Black-Scholes benchmark:\n"
      "------------------------\n"
      "S        %g\n"
      "E        %g\n"
      "r        %g\n"
      "sigma    %g\n"
      "T        %g\n"
      "M        %d\n",
      S, E, r, sigma, T, M);
  printf ("Confidence interval: (%g, %g)\n", interval.min, interval.max);

  return 0;
}
```

I have clearly linked `black_scholes` and `main()` together so I do not really understand why this is happening, it started happening when I removed the old number generator from the code and kept on happening even after doing the suitable changes in `make`, any help in fixing `make` would be appreciated

Comment: The function you try to call is not available. You are probably misspelling the name or you simply don't know the correct name of the Black-Scholes function. The name of the files (`.h` and `.cu`) do not need to have anything to do with the name of the function actually implementing the algorithm. Since you have been modifying the `.cu` file (?), you may also have mistakenly changed the name of the function in there.

Comment: I just verified and that is not the case, I change its name to myfunction in the `.cu` and `.h` and tried calling it and got the same thing

Comment: I do not think it is a coding related error, I just tried everything possible. I made the function to be just a print statement, I made sure all the brackets and semicolons before the function are correct so the function gets read properly and it all results in the same thing